# Django Admin - choices working for one Integer model, but not another

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I'm making a tea catalog in Django, and I'm having a bit of an issue with the models. I want some things in the database to have choices for 1-5, for certain ratings. For example, for the tea type, I want a caffine level of 1-5. I do this with the following code:

```
one_to_five_choices = zip(range(1,5+1), range(1,5+1))
...

class TeaType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, primary_key=True)
    steeping_temperature = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    steeping_time_minutes = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    caffeine_level = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=one_to_five_choices)
    directions = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

And it works perfectly!

[image]

However, I seemingly have the same code for ratings, and it does not show this box for the choices.

```
class Rating(models.Model):
    rating = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=one_to_five_choices)
    tea = models.ForeignKey(Tea)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} star rating for {} by {}".format(self.rating, self.tea, self.user.get_username())

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("user", "tea"),)
```

And here is the picture:[image]

There isn't anything interesting going on in the admin.py to cause this

```
for m in [TeaType, Brand, Ingredient, Picture, Rating]:
    admin.site.register(m)
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: I've read through all the code that generates formfields for the admin (see the `modelform_factory` function) and there's nothing that points out why this is happening. the factory function should not ignore that you're setting choices in the field. I think that if you can reproduce it, you've found yourself a bug and you may report it: https://code.djangoproject.com/newticket

Comment: Ok - I have no idea how I can make a smaller reproducible version of this, but I guess I'll file the ticket anyway.

Comment: nevermind my comment, i think @user61000 below is right

Comment: Yup - that fixed it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On python 3, `zip()` returns a generator.  your first model is exhausting that generator leaving no choices for the 2nd model.  wrapping `one_to_five_choices` in a `list()` call should do the trick.